# Problems with nginx. How to make an authenticated call to the API using jwt (Django)?

Tags: django, authentication, nginx, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have some problems with nginx and django-rest-framework. I've already been trying to figure out how to make an authenticated request to the API for about 24 hours. I'm really exhausted and hope somebody can help me.

I have the following nginx conf:

```
location / {

     if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' "GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' "Authorization, 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' "true";
     }

       uwsgi_pass  django;
       include     /path/to/your/mysite/uwsgi_params;, 
}
```

And the following code on the client side:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://api/v0/api-token-auth/', true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'JWT ' + getCookie("token"))

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(json));
```

And I always get 401 Unauthorized. I don't know what else I need to do to fix this problem.

Comment: i'm not sure but maybe you should add some CORS to your config, check this https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me.

Comment: And an interesting thing is I did nothing. I just added this app to my installed  apps and CorsMiddleware to the list of middlewares.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you, I will add the answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that django is blocking some headers for security reason to allow or block requests use CORS https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers